# Convert 2D Image to 3D Image Using JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html

I am Trying To Convert A 2D Image into The 3D Image And Here I did It.
But I didn't get any proper Output With This. It will be a pleasure if anyone helps me to get the proper 3d image as we see in video or games.

Also, Suggest The Another Way to Archive The result if you Think The Logic for 3d Block is not proper

HTML Code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" >
<head>
   <meta charset="UTF-8">
   <title>2D Image to 3D Object</title>
   <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css">
</head>
 <body>
   <div id="container"></div>
   <script src='http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/three.js/r80/three.min.js'></script>
   <script src='http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.0/jquery.min.js'></script>
   <script src='http://rawgit.com/mrdoob/three.js/master/examples/js/controls/OrbitControls.js'></script>
   <script  src="js/index.js"></script>
 </body>
</html>
```

JavaScript:

```js
"use strict";
var container = document.getElementById('container');
var scene, camera, renderer, controls;

var canvas = document.createElement('CANVAS');
canvas.width = 16;
canvas.height = 16;
var ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");

var img = new Image();
img.onload = function () {
    ctx.drawImage(img, 0, 0, 16, 16);
    init();
}
img.src = "data:image/png;base64,iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAABAAAAAQCAYAAAAf8/9hAAAAAXNSR0IArs4c6QAAAARnQU1BAACxjwv8YQUAAAAJcEhZcwAACxEAAAsRAX9kX5EAAAAYdEVYdFNvZnR3YXJlAHBhaW50Lm5ldCA0LjAuNWWFMmUAAACSSURBVDhPnZDdDYAgDIS7iokDOYsj+Ox8zuAWta0F2ggFfPigP3cXAiDiNHDSkagJIti0XC/TAdY8HVAzyzwJIlpm2aWiRWSWfS5o8Vl2zIwTHzcVKhoxM74xISNmxjeVgMjMfAcmpGdmfLPuCBsVGmL/pEUpkplu6fUFvZAslAA1O4Hu7cwigpHPalFe8CsA4QHINOMS97iyIAAAAABJRU5ErkJggg==";

function init() {
  scene = new THREE.Scene();
    scene.fog = new THREE.Fog(0xcccccc, 0.008);

  camera = new THREE.PerspectiveCamera(60, window.innerWidth/window.innerHeight, 0.01, 1000);
    camera.position.set(0, 3, 3);
    camera.lookAt(scene.position);

  controls = new THREE.OrbitControls(camera, container);
  //console.log('constrols');

    renderer = new THREE.WebGLRenderer({antialias:true});
    renderer.setClearColor(scene.fog.color);
  renderer.setSize(window.innerWidth, window.innerHeight);
    container.appendChild(renderer.domElement);

    var light = new THREE.PointLight(0xdddddd, 1, 100);
    light.position.set(3, 3, 3);
    scene.add(light);

  var swordGeometry = new THREE.CanvasGeometry(canvas, 1/16, false);
  var swordMaterial = new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial({vertexColors: THREE.FaceColors});
    var swordMesh = new THREE.Mesh(swordGeometry, swordMaterial);
    swordMesh.position.x = -0.5;
    swordMesh.position.y = 1;
    scene.add(swordMesh);

    resizeArea();
    window.addEventListener('resize', function(){resizeArea();}, false);
    render();
}

function resizeArea() {
    var newWidth = window.innerWidth;
    var newHeight = window.innerHeight;
    renderer.setSize(newWidth, newHeight);
    camera.aspect = newWidth / newHeight;
    camera.updateProjectionMatrix()
}

function render() {
    requestAnimationFrame( render );
    renderer.render(scene, camera);
}

/* I did this so I could avoid typing 3 lines */
THREE.Face3.prototype.set = function(a, b, c) {
    this.a = a;
    this.b = b;
    this.c = c;
};

/* Obviously this will not be good for larger images.
   If you want larger Images, https://wizgrav.github.io/three.js/runner/
   parameters:
        canvas - <CANVAS DOM Element>
          depth - <float> how far to extend the Image
          hasOpacity - <boolean> If the canvas has opacity
        material - <THREE.Material> The material to use on the geometry with THREE.MeshFaceMaterial();
   To use opacity:
        set hasOpacity to true,
        set a material to use with transparency
        set the Mesh material to THREE.MeshFaceMaterial(yourCanvasGeometry.materials());
    */
THREE.CanvasGeometry = function (canvas, depth, hasOpacity, material) {
    THREE.Geometry.call( this );
    var ctx = canvas.getContext('2d'),
        w = canvas.width, 
        h = canvas.height;
    this.materials = [];
    this.opacitys = [];
    for(var x=0;x<w;x++) {
        for(var y=0;y<h;y++) {
            var data = ctx.getImageData(x, y, x+1, y+1).data;
            if(data[3] !== 0) {
                var vectors = [];
                var v = new THREE.Vector3();
                var f = new THREE.Face3();
                f.color.setStyle("rgb("+data[0]+","+data[1]+","+data[2]+")");
                if(hasOpacity) {
                    if(this.opacitys.indexOf(data[3]/255) == -1) {
                        this.opacitys.push(data[3]/255);
                        var materialClone = material.clone();
                        materialClone.transparent = true;
                        materialClone.opacity = data[3]/255;
                        this.materials.push(materialClone);
                    }
                    f.materialIndex = this.opacitys.indexOf(data[3]/255);
                }
                v.set(x/w, -y/w, 0);
                this.vertices.push(v.clone());
                vectors.push(this.vertices.length-1);

                v.set((x+1)/w, -y/w, 0);
                this.vertices.push(v.clone());
                vectors.push(this.vertices.length-1);

                v.set((x+1)/w, (-y+1)/w, 0);
                this.vertices.push(v.clone());
                vectors.push(this.vertices.length-1);

                v.set(x/w, (-y+1)/w, 0);
                this.vertices.push(v.clone());
                vectors.push(this.vertices.length-1);

                v.set(x/w, -y/w, depth);
                this.vertices.push(v.clone());
                vectors.push(this.vertices.length-1);

                v.set((x+1)/w, -y/w, depth);
                this.vertices.push(v.clone());
                vectors.push(this.vertices.length-1);

                v.set((x+1)/w, (-y+1)/w, depth);
                this.vertices.push(v.clone());
                vectors.push(this.vertices.length-1);

                v.set(x/w, (-y+1)/w, depth);
                this.vertices.push(v.clone());
                vectors.push(this.vertices.length-1);

                f.set(vectors[2], vectors[1], vectors[0]);
                this.faces.push(f.clone());

                f.set(vectors[0], vectors[3], vectors[2]);
                this.faces.push(f.clone());

                f.set(vectors[4], vectors[5], vectors[6]);
                this.faces.push(f.clone());

                f.set(vectors[6], vectors[7], vectors[4]);
                this.faces.push(f.clone());

                //check left
                if(x-1 < 0 || ctx.getImageData(x-1, y, x, y+1).data[3] == 0) {
                    vectors = [];
                    v.set(x/w, -y/w, 0);
                    this.vertices.push(v.clone());
                    vectors.push(this.vertices.length-1);

                    v.set(x/w, (-y+1)/w, 0);
                    this.vertices.push(v.clone());
                    vectors.push(this.vertices.length-1);

                    v.set(x/w, (-y+1)/w, depth);
                    this.vertices.push(v.clone());
                    vectors.push(this.vertices.length-1);

                    v.set(x/w, -y/w, depth);
                    this.vertices.push(v.clone());
                    vectors.push(this.vertices.length-1);

                    f.set(vectors[2], vectors[1], vectors[0]);
                    this.faces.push(f.clone());
                    f.set(vectors[0], vectors[3], vectors[2]);
                    this.faces.push(f.clone());
                }
                // check right
                if(x+1 > w || ctx.getImageData(x+1, y, x+2, y+1).data[3] == 0) {
                    vectors = [];
                    v.set((x+1)/w, -y/w, 0);
                    this.vertices.push(v.clone());
                    vectors.push(this.vertices.length-1);

                    v.set((x+1)/w, (-y+1)/w, 0);
                    this.vertices.push(v.clone());
                    vectors.push(this.vertices.length-1);

                    v.set((x+1)/w, (-y+1)/w, depth);
                    this.vertices.push(v.clone());
                    vectors.push(this.vertices.length-1);

                    v.set((x+1)/w, -y/w, depth);
                    this.vertices.push(v.clone());
                    vectors.push(this.vertices.length-1);

                    f.set(vectors[0], vectors[1], vectors[2]);
                    this.faces.push(f.clone());
                    f.set(vectors[2], vectors[3], vectors[0]);
                    this.faces.push(f.clone());
                }
                //check top
                if(y+1 > h || ctx.getImageData(x, y+1, x+1, y+2).data[3] == 0) {
                    vectors = [];
                    v.set(x/w, (-y)/w, 0);
                    this.vertices.push(v.clone());
                    vectors.push(this.vertices.length-1);

                    v.set((x+1)/w, (-y)/w, 0);
                    this.vertices.push(v.clone());
                    vectors.push(this.vertices.length-1);

                    v.set((x+1)/w, (-y)/w, depth);
                    this.vertices.push(v.clone());
                    vectors.push(this.vertices.length-1);

                    v.set(x/w, (-y)/w, depth);
                    this.vertices.push(v.clone());
                    vectors.push(this.vertices.length-1);

                    f.set(vectors[0], vectors[1], vectors[2]);
                    this.faces.push(f.clone());
                    f.set(vectors[2], vectors[3], vectors[0]);
                    this.faces.push(f.clone());
                }
                //check bottom
                if(y-1 < 0 || ctx.getImageData(x, y-1, x+1, y).data[3] == 0) {
                    vectors = [];
                    v.set(x/w, (-y+1)/w, 0);
                    this.vertices.push(v.clone());
                    vectors.push(this.vertices.length-1);

                    v.set((x+1)/w, (-y+1)/w, 0);
                    this.vertices.push(v.clone());
                    vectors.push(this.vertices.length-1);

                    v.set((x+1)/w, (-y+1)/w, depth);
                    this.vertices.push(v.clone());
                    vectors.push(this.vertices.length-1);

                    v.set(x/w, (-y+1)/w, depth);
                    this.vertices.push(v.clone());
                    vectors.push(this.vertices.length-1);

                    f.set(vectors[0], vectors[3], vectors[2]);
                    this.faces.push(f.clone());
                    f.set(vectors[2], vectors[1], vectors[0]);
                    this.faces.push(f.clone());
                }
            }
        }
    }

    this.mergeVertices();
    this.computeFaceNormals();
    this.computeVertexNormals();
};
THREE.CanvasGeometry.prototype = Object.create(THREE.Geometry.prototype);
THREE.CanvasGeometry.prototype.constructor = THREE.CanvasGeometry;
```

Comment: ok got it. @Cerbrus